# Change wallpaper in SLAX

Tags: live-usb, wallpaper

On the SLAX website there is [documentation](https://www.slax.org/customize.php) for changing the wallpaper. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. After creating the module as instructed I moved it to `/run/initramfs/memory/data/slax/modules/` and rebooted. I expected to see the new wallpaper now, but it is still the standard one.

In `/usr/share/wallpapers/` there is still the standard wallpaper. However, the module is mounted and the new wallpaper is in `/run/initramfs/memory/bundles/wallpaper.sb/usr/share/wallpapers/`.

I'm running SLAX version 11.4.0. The documentation linked above mentions SLAX version 9.6.4 at some point. Is the documentation still up to date?